# How I can generate Concatenation between two chars based on previous combine using java 8?

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-8

I'm working on an a problem trying to generate all the possible combination between two chars based on early generated combine using java 8

for example :

```
private static final String LETTER_RANGE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxz";

from this letter rang I want to extract all differents combine between two chars XX

for example : 

zz,zx,zw....za 
xz,xx,xw....xa
..,..,..,..,..
az,ax,aw... aa

My problem is I need to generate those combination at runtime based on previous combine : 

String value = generate("zx") // this should return 'zw'
```

Can any one helpe me on any idea how can use java 8 loops,Stream,String to do this Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean with combination. Please clarify how you're coming from `"zx"` to `"zw"`

Comment: I mean concatenation between chars in the LETTER_RANGE

Comment: `String generate(String string) {
        char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
        chars[1]--;
        return new String(chars);
    }`,  `generate("zx") // this return 'zw' `

Comment: Do you want just to generate all combinations or do you want to do something “based on previous combine”? And does it need to be backwards, as your example suggests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple character arithmetics. As `char`s can be incremented and compared:

```
final List<String> permutations = new ArrayList<>(26 * 26);
for (char[] array = {'a', 'a'}; array[0] <= 'z'; array[0]++) {
    for (array[1] = 'a'; array[1] <= 'z'; array[1]++) {
        permutations.add(new String(array));
    }
}
```

This piece of code creates every combination of all characters between `a` and `z` inclusive and adds them to a `List`.

This is possible because in ASCII the character value of `a` (97) is smaller than the one from `z` (122).

I've also used some optimizations, like the use of an `array` inside the `for-loop` to hold the current combination of 2 chars. This array can then also be directly used to create a new string, with the string constructor: `String(char[])`.

Answer (score 1):

Tools one might use are:

```
char ch = LETTER_RANGE.charAt(2); // 'c'
int ix = LETTER_RANGE.indexOf(ch); // 2
```

Using the single `char[]` array is probably much easier, so the method might look like:

```
String next(String combination) {
    char[] chars = combination.toCharArray();
    char ch = chars[1];
    if (...) {
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like very bad solution of task for me. But if you really need it, it can be done like this.

```
    private static final String LETTER_RANGE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxz";

public String findNext(String prev) {
    if(prev==null || prev.length()<2)
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid argument");

    int char1Index = LETTER_RANGE.indexOf(prev.charAt(0));
    int char2Index = LETTER_RANGE.indexOf(prev.charAt(1));
    char2Index--;
    if (char2Index < 0) {
        char1Index--;
        char2Index = LETTER_RANGE.length() - 1;
    }
    if (char1Index < 0) {
        return null;// or what you need here.
    }
    return new String(new char[]{LETTER_RANGE.charAt(char1Index), LETTER_RANGE.charAt(char2Index)});
}
```

And the task find all Concatenation between two chars from predefined list I would do like this

```
public List findAll() {
    List<String> result=new ArrayList<>();
    char[] chars=LETTER_RANGE.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<chars.length;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<chars.length;j++)
        result.add(new String(new char[]{chars[i],chars[j]}));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern in your example reminds me of Excel columns. Excel names its columns with letters from A to Z, and then the sequence goes AA, AB, AC... AZ, BA, BB, etc. So if we interpret your combinations as Excel column titles the task could be reworded to:

> Given a column title as appears in an Excel sheet, find the next
>   column title (or previous as shown in your expected output).

To do this you can write a method that accepts a string as a parameter (like "zf") and returns the actual column number. And then add or substract 1 to get the number of the next or previos column and convert the number back to string. Example:

```
public final class ExcelColumn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "zx";
        System.out.println(getPreviousColumn(str));
    }

    public static int toColumnNumber(String column) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < column.length(); i++) {
            result *= 26;
            result += column.charAt(i) - 'a' + 1;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String toColumnName(int number) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int num = number - 1;
        while (num >=  0) {
            int numChar = (num % 26)  + 97;
            sb.append((char)numChar);
            num = (num  / 26) - 1;
        }
        return sb.reverse().toString();
    }
    public static String getNextColumn(String s) {
        return toColumnName( toColumnNumber(s)+1);
    }
    public static String getPreviousColumn(String s) {
        return toColumnName( toColumnNumber(s)-1);
    }
}
```

ToDo:

- Input validiation and
- exception handling

Pros:

- You can use this even if your combined string length is > 2
- can be easily modified to use with uppercase letters
- You can do something like from 'be' to 'cf' to generate all combinations which fall in this range if necessary

Cons:

- May be to much code for a simple task. Look at @Andrii Vdovychenko's
  comment which solves the problem in few lines